# call action from another action rails to save pdfs with prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn, prawnto

I have an action to generate pdfs with prawn

```
def savepdfs
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf {} # Create PDF file and saves in /pdf/print.pdf.
    logger.info ":::::::::::::::::  PDF COVER PAGE CREATED  :::::::::::::::::"
  end
end
```

I don't want to show the pdf to the user . Instead I just want to call this from another action

```
def mainaction
    #I want to call something like savepdfs(:format => :pdf)
end
```

How do I do this ?

Comment: And the result of your first action is return in your second action ? Why don't do a redirection ?

Comment: @shingara i commented savepdfs(:format => :pdf ) because it didn't work. If that had called the savepdfs i would have redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it as a private controller method

```
def savepdfs
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf { generate_pdf } # Create PDF file and saves in /pdf/print.pdf.
    logger.info ":::::::::::::::::  PDF COVER PAGE CREATED  :::::::::::::::::"
  end
end

def mainaction
  generate_pdf
end

private

def generate_pdf
  # Create PDF file and saves in /pdf/print.pdf.
end
```

Comment: how do I create a pdf and save it from generate_pdf?

Comment: the same way you do it from your action

Comment: generating the pdf from the controller works . I though it should be done from the view only. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an XY Problem*. You don't want to call another action, you want to put business logic in the model where it belongs.

* http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341